# Javascript: comparación entre dos arreglos de objetos y extraer id por coincidencia

Tags: javascript, array, comparaciones, id

tengo este caso, tengo dos arreglos:
**arr1** con n objetos y **arr2** con n objetos , el arr1 contiene **_id** el cual existe en el arr2 como **f_id** , debo comparar los arreglos en cada posición y por cada coincidencia debo extraer el **id** en el arr1.

Para asi obtener una salida esperada en un nuevo arreglo :

`[33,33,34,34]`

Hasta ahora voy realizando la comparación entre ambos por el _id y f_id

```js
let arr1 = [
  {
    "id": "33",
    "_id": "5f487c3adf3c3e493e53c4f2",
    "nombre": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": "34",
    "_id": "5f4f150b6589496b932b0172",
    "nombre": "b"
  }
]

let arr2 = [
  {
    "_id": "5f488b999084030f052cdca4",
    "f_id": "5f487c3adf3c3e493e53c4f2"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5f4d8ebf9711d46f126c560e",
    "f_id": "5f487c3adf3c3e493e53c4f2"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5f4fd08510ad1b6c4a44fa32",
    "f_id": "5f4f150b6589496b932b0172"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5f4fd08c97d7fc2c6d321ee4",
    "f_id": "5f4f150b6589496b932b0172"
  }
]

const compara = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const lis = arr2.filter(i => {
    const obj = arr1.find(e => e._id == i.f_id)
    return obj
  })
  return lis
}

console.log('Respuesta', compara(arr1, arr2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recuerda que filter no convierte objetos, solo los acepta o rechaza segun el valor que devuelve si es true o false (o equivalentes ej: null, 1, undefined etc.)

```js
        let arr1 = [{
                "id": "33",
                "_id": "5f487c3adf3c3e493e53c4f2",
                "nombre": "a"
            },
            {
                "id": "34",
                "_id": "5f4f150b6589496b932b0172",
                "nombre": "b"
            }
        ]

        let arr2 = [{
                "_id": "5f488b999084030f052cdca4",
                "f_id": "5f487c3adf3c3e493e53c4f2"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f4d8ebf9711d46f126c560e",
                "f_id": "5f487c3adf3c3e493e53c4f2"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f4fd08510ad1b6c4a44fa32",
                "f_id": "5f4f150b6589496b932b0172"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f4fd08c97d7fc2c6d321ee4",
                "f_id": "5f4f150b6589496b932b0172"
            }
        ]

        var comparador = (arr1, arr2) => {
            let responseArray = [];
            let lis = arr2.filter(i => {
                let obj = arr1.find(e => {
                    if (e._id == i.f_id) {
                        let copyArray2Element = i;
                        copyArray2Element.id = e.id;
                        responseArray.push(copyArray2Element);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            });
            let responseArrayOnlyIds = responseArray.map(e => e.id);
            return responseArrayOnlyIds;
        }

        console.log('Respuesta', comparador(arr1, arr2))
```